# setting the hitbox when using css transform:scale(x);

Tags: css, transform, scale, onmouseover

Is it possible to set the hitbox of an element when using `-webkit-transform:scale(4);`?

http://jsfiddle.net/bnA7L/

In the jsfiddle example above I have two divs. WHen you rollover one, you need to move your mouse to the edge of the new boundary to get it to return to its original size.

I want it to return to its original size as soon as the user's mouse moves out of the original hitbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in CSS when you add 2 children for each div. 
Child 1 doesn't scale and acts as hitbox. 
Child 2 scales, only when you hover over child 1.

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/q7vbD/

Comment: Yes it should, you can try to add float:right for #divtwo for example

Answer (score 2):

The [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) property makes this very easy.

First, wrap your content with a parent and a child:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
Hover me
</div>
</div>
```

Then, disable pointer events on the child, which allows pointer events to drip down to the parent element. Then use the parent's :hover pseudo-class to transform the child:

```
.child {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

The parent remains its original size, so the "hitbox" for the hover effect remains at the original size, too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use jQuery or JavaScript to check the co-ordinates prior to the transform, and then listen out for the `mousemove` event on the DOM.